# Returning a set of the most recent rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve the latest set of rows from a source table containing a foreign key, a date and other fields present. A sample set of data could be:

```
create table #tmp (primaryId int, foreignKeyId int, startDate datetime, 
                                                    otherfield varchar(50))

insert into #tmp values (1, 1, '1 jan 2010', 'test 1')
insert into #tmp values (2, 1, '1 jan 2011', 'test 2')
insert into #tmp values (3, 2, '1 jan 2013', 'test 3')
insert into #tmp values (4, 2, '1 jan 2012', 'test 4')
```

The form of data that I'm hoping to retrieve is:

```
foreignKeyId maxStartDate            otherfield
------------ ----------------------- -------------------------------------------
1            2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 test 2
2            2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 test 3
```

That is, just one row per `foreignKeyId` showing the latest start date and associated other fields - the `primaryId` is irrelevant.

I've managed to come up with:

```
select t.foreignKeyId, t.startDate, t.otherField from #tmp t
    inner join (
                  select foreignKeyId, max(startDate) as maxStartDate
                      from #tmp
                      group by foreignKeyId
               ) s
           on t.foreignKeyId = s.foreignKeyId and s.maxStartDate = t.startDate
```

but (a) this uses inner queries, which I suspect may lead to performance issues, and (b) it gives repeated rows if two rows in the original table have the same `foreignKeyId` and `startDate`.

Is there a query that will return just the first match for each foreign key and start date?

Comment: Have you tried a distinct after the initial select ???  It seems this would solve the repeat row problem... unless there are other fields involved that you are not showing that are not distinct.

Comment: @RThomas The `otherField` would not necessarily be distinct here, which rules that out I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your sql server version, try the following:

```
select *
from (
    select *, rnum = ROW_NUMBER() over (
      partition by #tmp.foreignKeyId
      order by #tmp.startDate desc)
    from #tmp
) t
where t.rnum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to fix your attempt as opposed to re-engineering it then

```
select t.foreignKeyId, t.startDate, t.otherField from #tmp t
inner join (
  select foreignKeyId, max(startDate) as maxStartDate, max(PrimaryId) as Latest
  from #tmp
  group by foreignKeyId
           ) s
on t.primaryId = s.latest
```

would have done the job, assuming PrimaryID increases over time.

Qualms about inner query would have been laid to rest as well assuming some indexes.

Comment: This is giving the wrong result for the test data - I'm afraid your assumption about the primary id is incorrect. As for indexes, this is a case of "someone else's database" unfortunately!

Comment: Um, so what defines the most recent record when they have the same start date and same foreignkeyid?

Comment: My point is more that for `foreignKeyId` 2, you're returning a `startDate` in 2012 and an `otherField` value of "test 4", not 2013 and "test 3". I did say in the question "the latest start date and associated other fields". So your query gives the wrong result for the data as given, without even taking into consideration duplicate dates.